# Selenium webdriver not able to locate an element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a element which is a link by giving the below mentioned command:

driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("backup")).click();

however selenium is not able to locate the element.

i am new to selenium webdriver

[html for the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii3ku.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML as text.

Answer (score 0):

Sonu, Please try following:-

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("page-content")).click();
```

For accurate answer please share the website link.

Comment: the website link is https://www.warmane.com/account. i tried with page content by giving absolute xpath but it wont find it that way.

Comment: Thanks for website link, but I could not find link 'back up'. Could you please paste navigation for my ease.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to use "ByClassName" fonction? it can works for this case.

Other option:

try this:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'YOUR TEXT')])")).click();

Hope this will help.